# Macbook crashes randomly. CPU problem?

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, cpu, logs

MacBook Pro (Mid-2014 11,3) (C02P42JBG3QP) 11.6

My MacBook will crash randomly throughout the day as I'm working. If I leave it open and don't touch it, it will be fine. But as I use multiple apps, the screen will turn black and it will die. I thought it was the battery, so I replaced it, but it's still doing the same thing. Could it be crashing when there's a bump in CPU usage?

The last crash was around 21:05

Logs right before crash up to the crash:

```
default 21:04:43.109157-0500    apsd    <private>: Acknowledging power change event after waiting
default 21:04:43.109498-0500    powerd  Need to wake in at most 72000.000000 seconds to check remaining battery capacity. (capacity=70, threshold=50, timeToThreshold=72000.000000, timeToLowDelay=10800.000000, timeUntilStandby=86400, minimumInterval=28800.000000)
default 21:04:43.109584-0500    powerd  Adaptive standby wake request after 71999.999905 secs
default 21:04:43.109652-0500    powerd  Denying darkwake for proximity as feature is disabled. proxEnableFlags:0x0
default 21:04:43.110061-0500    kernel  PMRD: _userScheduledAlarmMask 0x2
default 21:04:43.111246-0500    kernel  PMRD: SleepServiceWakeCalendarKey 2021/10/28 06:05:12
default 21:04:43.111264-0500    kernel  PMRD: next alarm (SleepServiceWakeCalendarKey) 2021/10/28 06:05:12
default 21:04:43.111268-0500    kernel  PMRD: scheduled alarm mask 0x8
default 21:04:43.112138-0500    kernel  PM response took 2980 ms (86, powerd)
default 21:04:43.112365-0500    kernel  PMRD: tellChangeDown ON_STATE->SLEEP_STATE
default 21:04:43.112371-0500    kernel  PMRD: trace point 0x12
default 21:04:43.112497-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[0] to __kernel__
default 21:04:43.112503-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[1] to __kernel__
default 21:04:43.112504-0500    kernel  PMRD: sysPowerDownHandler message kIOMessageSystemWillSleep
default 21:04:43.112554-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[2] to com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager
default 21:04:43.112601-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[3] to com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform
default 21:04:43.112648-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[4] to com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily
default 21:04:43.112698-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[5] to com.apple.driver.AppleSMC
default 21:04:43.112749-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[6] to com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily
default 21:04:43.112795-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[7] to com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily
default 21:04:43.112842-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[8] to com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily
default 21:04:43.112891-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[9] to com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family
default 21:04:43.112960-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[10] to com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC
default 21:04:43.113030-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[11] to com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard
default 21:04:43.113080-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[12] to com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily
default 21:04:43.113126-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[13] to com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family
default 21:04:43.113209-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[14] to com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU
default 21:04:43.113269-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[15] to com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin
default 21:04:43.113326-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[16] to com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface
default 21:04:43.113387-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[17] to com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily
default 21:04:43.113395-0500    kernel  GTrace synchronization point 214
default 21:04:43.113425-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[17] response from com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily took 0 ms (ack in 90000000 us)
default 21:04:43.113477-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[18] to com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl
default 21:04:43.113534-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[19] to com.apple.driver.AGPM
default 21:04:43.113540-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[20] to com.apple.driver.AGPM
default 21:04:43.113606-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemWillSleep[21] to com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy
default 21:04:43.113687-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[22] to __kernel__
default 21:04:43.113692-0500    kernel  DK: allowPowerChange
default 21:04:43.113714-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[22] response from __kernel__ took 0 ms (ack in 60000000 us)
default 21:04:43.113715-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[23] to __kernel__
default 21:04:43.113718-0500    kernel  PMRD: sysPowerDownHandler message kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange
default 21:04:43.113718-0500    kernel  PMRD: sysPowerDownHandler cap 9 -> 0 (flags 1)
default 21:04:43.113720-0500    kernel  PMRD: evaluateSystemSleepPolicyEarly
default 21:04:43.113739-0500    kernel  PMRD: phase 1, standby 1 delay 10800 timer 86400, poweroff 1 delay 259200 timer 259182, hibernate 0x3
default 21:04:43.113744-0500    kernel  PMRD: sleep factors 0x200800, RTCAlarmScheduled, LocalUserActivity
default 21:04:43.113759-0500    kernel  PMRD: sleep params v2, type 2, flags 0x0, wake 0x390f, timer 0, poweroff 0
default 21:04:43.113761-0500    kernel  PMRD: sysPowerDownHandler max wait 20 s
default 21:04:43.113769-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[23] response from __kernel__ took 0 ms (ack in 20000000 us)
default 21:04:43.113775-0500    kernel  PMRD: disk_sync_callout ps=4
default 21:04:43.113811-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[24] to com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager
default 21:04:43.113850-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[25] to com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform
default 21:04:43.116600-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[26] to com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily
default 21:04:43.116648-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[27] to com.apple.driver.AppleSMC
default 21:04:43.116699-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[28] to com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily
default 21:04:43.116746-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[29] to com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily
default 21:04:43.116782-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[30] to com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily
default 21:04:43.116827-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[31] to com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family
default 21:04:43.116869-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[32] to com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC
default 21:04:43.117468-0500    loginwindow clamshellStateChanged | Clamshell state changed: closed=1, shouldSleepWhenClosed=0
default 21:04:43.117516-0500    sharingd    Clamshell change detected (clamshell closed: YES, clamshell sleep on close: NO)
default 21:04:43.117532-0500    loginwindow -[LWAuthServiceManager clamshellStateChanged:] | clamshell closed, but screen is not locked.  Ignoring
default 21:04:43.117616-0500    NotificationCenter  Clamshell changed <private>
default 21:04:43.116888-0500    kernel  ARPT: 1313.150046: AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Sleep
default 21:04:43.116910-0500    kernel  ARPT: 1313.150069: IOPMPowerSource Information: onSleep,  SleepType: Normal Sleep,  'ExternalConnected': No, 'TimeRemaining': 206,
default 21:04:43.116919-0500    kernel  ARPT: 1313.150079: wl0: powerChange: *** BONJOUR/MDNS OFFLOADS ARE NOT RUNNING.
default 21:04:43.116970-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[33] to com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard
default 21:04:43.117006-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[34] to com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily
default 21:04:43.117042-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[35] to com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family
default 21:04:43.117078-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[36] to com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU
default 21:04:43.117114-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[37] to com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin
default 21:04:43.117151-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[38] to com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface
default 21:04:43.117189-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[39] to com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily
default 21:04:43.117191-0500    kernel  GTrace synchronization point 21b
default 21:04:43.117232-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[40] to com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl
default 21:04:43.117266-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[41] to com.apple.driver.AGPM
default 21:04:43.117269-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[42] to com.apple.driver.AGPM
default 21:04:43.117305-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[43] to com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy
default 21:04:43.117341-0500    kernel  PMRD: trace point 0x12 msgType 0xe0000340 detail 0x00015f90
default 21:04:43.117347-0500    kernel  PMRD: Clamshell disabled
default 21:04:43.117350-0500    kernel  PMRD: clamshell closed 1, disabled 1/0, desktopMode 0, ac 0
default 21:04:43.117356-0500    kernel  PMRD: clamshell closed 1, disabled 1/0, desktopMode 0, ac 0
default 21:04:43.117383-0500    kernel  IOTimeSyncLocalClockPort::handleGeneralNotification <private>
default 21:04:43.117434-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[22] ack from __kernel__ took 3 ms
default 21:04:43.131498-0500    kernel  ACMRM-S: _saveAll: pushing policy -> daemon (gen=3 len=41).
default 21:04:43.408672-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[39] ack from com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily took 295 ms
default 21:04:43.516201-0500    kernel  PMRD: disk_sync_callout finish
default 21:04:43.516230-0500    kernel  PMRD: kIOMessageSystemCapabilityChange[23] ack from __kernel__ took 402 ms
default 21:04:43.516242-0500    kernel  PMRD: trace point 0x13
default 21:04:43.516479-0500    NotificationCenter  clamshell closed, not counted as a display
default 21:04:43.516505-0500    NotificationCenter  0 usable displays
default 21:04:43.564035-0500    kernel  **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport][powerStateWillChangeTo] -- System Sleep -- SleepType is kIOPMSleepTypeNormalSleep ****
default 21:04:43.564057-0500    kernel  001313.597212 BRCM20702 Hub@14300000: IOUSBHostDevice::forcePowerGated: kPowerStateOn timeout 0ms
default 21:04:43.597886-0500    kernel  001313.631036 BRCM20702 Hub@14300000: IOUSBHostDevice::powerStateWillChangeToGated: kPowerStateOn
default 21:04:43.597944-0500    kernel  001313.631100 BRCM20702 Hub@14300000: IOUSBHostDevice::setPowerStateGated: kPowerStateSuspended -> kPowerStateOn
default 21:04:43.597979-0500    kernel  001313.631135 BRCM20702 Hub@14300000: IOUSBHostDevice::setPowerStateGated: resuming pipes
default 21:04:43.598046-0500    kernel  001313.631195 BRCM20702 Hub@14300000: IOUSBHostDevice::forcePowerGated: kPowerStateOn completed with 0x00000000 after 33ms
default 21:04:43.598062-0500    kernel  001313.631216 BRCM20702 Hub@14300000: IOUSBHostDevice::message: kUSBHostMessageUpdateIdlePolicy from IOUSBHostInterface@0 [<private>]
default 21:04:43.598081-0500    kernel  001313.631236 BRCM20702 Hub@14300000: IOUSBHostDevice::updateIdlePolicyGated: IOUSBHostInterface@0 [<private>] has not enabled an idle policy
default 21:04:43.598089-0500    kernel  001313.631247 BRCM20702 Hub@14300000: IOUSBHostDevice::updateIdlePolicyGated: consensus idle policy timeout 0ms
default 21:04:43.598444-0500    kernel  001313.631601 BRCM20702 Hub@14300000: IOUSBHostDevice::powerChangeDone:
default 21:04:43.598483-0500    kernel  001313.631633 BRCM20702 Hub@14300000: IOUSBHostDevice::updateIdlePolicyGated: IOUSBHostInterface@0 [<private>] has not enabled an idle policy
default 21:04:43.598493-0500    kernel  001313.631650 BRCM20702 Hub@14300000: IOUSBHostDevice::updateIdlePolicyGated: consensus idle policy timeout 0ms
default 21:04:43.616338-0500    WindowServer    [HID] [MT] dispatchEvent Dispatching event with 2 children, _eventMask=0x21 _childEventMask=0x3 Cancel=0 Touching=0 inRange=0
default 21:04:43.965981-0500    kernel  AppleCredentialManager: powerStateWillChangeToGated: SYSTEM WILL SLEEP.
```

Comment: I noticed the last line `kernel  AppleCredentialManager: powerStateWillChangeToGated: SYSTEM WILL SLEEP`

Comment: sometimes it sleeps, and then sometimes it will fully crash. But the logs show nothing for the crash

Comment: Rule out hardware by testing a clean OS, without any of your usual settings. But those discrete GPUs frequently had problems.

Comment: @benwiggy I just reinstalled the OS, no restored backup

Comment: Then it does sound like a hardware problem.

Comment: @benwiggy how can I do a hardware diagnostic?

Comment: Take it to an Apple Store.

Comment: They just recommended I buy a new computer because they "think" the battery is old. The battery has 12 cycles. They didn't help me at all.

Comment: Was this an Apple Store, or a third-party authorised dealer? They should at least perform diagnostics.  12 full discharges over 7 years seems unlikely.

Comment: Its a new battery. They performed a hardware diagnostic and found no issues.

Comment: When fetching shutdown causes, im getting this:    `coe@Coe ~ % log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Previous shutdown cause"' --last 24h
2021-11-02 06:00:03.006825-0500 0x25ef     Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: -128
2021-11-02 09:57:41.772479-0500 0xbe       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: -128
2021-11-02 12:35:57.723712-0500 0xbe       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: -128
`

Comment: apparently its kernel panics ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Control-F to search for "panic" and found that it was kernel panics. The shutdown reasons were code -128, -124, 6, 4, and -60. I re-installed the OS that originally came with the machine, used `csrutil disable` and have not had a kernel panic since.

Answer (score -1):

I would try over clocking your CPU then see if that crashes it. If it does, then reboot in Safe mode, take a look at the logs and see what the cause is right before the crash.

Comment: How do I overclock the CPU?